# Adding Flow type checking to styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, flowtype, styled-components

I'm trying to get to grips with using styled-components with flow static type checking.
This is a footer element I have that is **flow correct**:

```
export const Footer: ComponentType<{}> = styled.div`
    p {
        color: #cccccc;
        font-family: ${({ theme: { fontPrimary } }) => fontPrimary};
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
`;
```

I'm trying to refactor it so that I can de-structure the props as per a method I saw here: [styled-component issue 2878](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/2878), this is not coming out as **flow correct** but it does work:

```
export const Footer = styled.div(
           ({ theme: { fontPrimary } }) => `
  p {
      color: #cccccc;
      font-family: ${fontPrimary};
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 0;
  }
`);
```

My error is: `Cannot call 'styled.div' because  function [1] is incompatible with  array type [2].Flow(InferError)`

I've tried a number of different types but can't quite figure out what exactly it means/how to format it. If theres any good reference guides to using flow that I might have missed please let me know!

I think it has something to do with injecting props into HOC's [Flow documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/hoc/#injecting-props-) But I don't know what types I need to add.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add all the error output to the question?

Comment: @AlexSavin I already have provided the entire error message, unless theres a way to increase verbosity which I don't know about its a flow error: ```Cannot call 'styled.div' because  function [1] is incompatible with  array type [2].Flow(InferError)```